# gpg not prompting a password for file decryption

Tags: password, encryption, gpg

I can encrypt a file with gpg 2.3.8, (not using keys), but I can't *decrypt* it.

```
[user@test ~]$ gpg -c tarredzip.tar.gz
```

That prompts for a password (I'm just using "test", so I get a warning about short passwords). It produces `tarredzip.tar.gz.gpg`.

But sometimes (1):

```
[user@test ~]$ gpg -d tarredzip.tar.gz.gpg
gpg: AES256.CFB encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
```

There is no prompt for a password. The file stays encrypted.

Or sometimes (2):

```
[user@test ~]$ gpg -d tarredzip.tar.gz.gpg
```

I get a prompt for password, enter it, then:

```
gpg: AES256.CFB encrypted data
gpg: encrypted with 1 passphrase
testfiles/0000755000175000017500000000000014433124023011572 5ustar  userusertestfiles/file30000644000175000017500000000000014433123725012515 0ustar  userusertestfiles/file10000644000175000017500000000000014433123725012513 0ustar  userusertestfiles/file20000644000175000017500000000000014433123725
```

The contents (paths/filenames) of my tarball are printed in that last line, but no file is decrypted.

What am I doing wrong?

(Notes:

- Using Fedora 37
- The tarball is very small, 3 files.
- The files in the tarball are empty, just files names)

---

** **SOLUTION** **
It seems that entering the command *without any flags* will work (i.e. password, decryption, restoration of file).
So:

```
$ gpg tarredzip.tar.gz.gpg
```

produces `tarredzip.tar.gz`.

Also, specifying a file as a destination seems to work with the `-d` flag. e.g.:

```
$ gpg -d tarredzip.tar.gz.gpg > otherfile
```

creates output in `otherfile`.

**Note, YMMV. So test it before you rely on it!**

Comment: In (2) the encrypted file -- the one and only file, tarredzip.tar.gz -- is decrypted, and is output to the terminal because you used `-d` without `-o` -- see the man page. In spite of being named with `.gz` that tar was not gzip'ed -- the data you see _is_ the tar format. If you want to decrypt a tar _and_ extract file(s) from it, run `gpg -d ... | tar x`. (If some other tar file is in fact gzip'ed or otherwise compressed, as is common, with GNU tar as on RH/FC do `tar xz` for gzip, `tar xj` for bzip2, etc; see the man page.)